# How to find the unit tangent, the principal normal and the curvature of $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

I need help with this problem:

> Sketch the semi ellipse $C$ defined by $$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4^2}=1 \quad\quad\quad\quad x\leq0$$Assuming a "clockwise" orientation of $C$ (from $(0,-2)$ to $(0,2)$), find the unit tangent, the principal normal and the curvature to C at $\left(\frac{-3}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\in C$.

I parametrized the ellipse like this: $x=3\cos t$ and $y=-2\sin t$, where $t\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$

After that I calculated the first and second derivative of the parametrization: $$f'(t)=(-3\sin t, -2\cos t)$$ $$f''(t)=(-3\cos t, 2\sin t)$$ Then I tried to calculate the unit tangent, the principal normal and the curvature at the given point.

For that, I found $t$ by doint $\frac{-3}{\sqrt{2}}=3\cos t\Rightarrow t=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=-2\sin t\Rightarrow t=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and since $t\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$, I chose $t=\frac{3\pi}{4}$

**(1)** $T(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{\Vert f'(t)\Vert}$=$\left(\frac{-3\sin t}{\sqrt{9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t}}, \frac{-2\cos t}{\sqrt{9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t}}\right)$, thus $T(\frac{3\pi}{4})=\left(\frac{-3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{26}},\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{26}} \right)$.

**(2)** I tried to calculate the principal normal with the formula $N(t)=\frac{T'(t)}{\Vert T'(t)\Vert}$, but I really got stuck at calculating the norm of $T'(t)$. I found that $T'(t)=\left(\frac{-3(2\cos t (9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t)-5\sin (2t)\sin t}{2(9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t)\sqrt{9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t}}, -\frac{-2\sin t(2(9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t)\sqrt{9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t})-5\sin (2t)\cos t}{(9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t)\sqrt{9\sin^2 t+4\cos^2 t}} \right)$. I don't know if I'm correct. I tried to calculate the norm of that, but I couldn't.

**(3)** I need **(2)**, so I can use $\kappa(t)=\frac{\Vert T'(t)\Vert}{\Vert f'(t)\Vert}$, or as one of the formulas that appear in my book $\kappa(q)=\frac{f''(a)\cdot N(q)}{\Vert f'(a)\Vert^2}$.

Please, I need help with calculating $N(t)$, also, I don't know if it is correct, but a friend of mine used the fact that $N(t)\cdot T(t)=0$ to calculate $N(t)$, how can I use this?